# How to run code on the second core on Raspberry Pico

Tags: c, microcontroller, cortex-m, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to get multicore working on my pico,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/multicore.h"

void core1_main()
{

    stdio_init_all();

    while (1)
    {
        uint32_t t = multicore_fifo_pop_blocking();
        printf("hellow world %d \n", t);
    }
}

int main()
{
    multicore_launch_core1(&core1_main);
    uint32_t i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        sleep_ms(250);
        multicore_fifo_push_blocking(i++);
    }
}
```

This is a very basic task I'm trying to get to work. I'm trying to learn more about this multicore magic. Basically I'm starting waiting on core1 for some data to come through. Then I simply print it out and wait for the next piece of data.
On core 0 I push a number onto the FIFO once every 250ms.
I don't get any error in compilation but running the code produces no output whatsoever.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there something that I should pat attention to?

I've tried quite a few things to get something multicore, but no use.

**UPDATE**
This gives me some output.
I added a wait for the USB to get connected and initialised. Now I get some message from core 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/multicore.h"

// const uint led = PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN;

void core1_main()
{
    printf("hellow world from second core");
    printf("hellow world from second core");
    printf("hellow world from second core");
}

int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    while (!stdio_usb_connected())
        ;
    while (!stdio_usb_init())
        ;

    multicore_launch_core1(core1_main);
    printf("hellow wow \n");

    uint32_t i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("hellow nice %d\n", i++);
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

This is the output I get. Notice the message from second core comes through only once.I confused, why?

Also changing the position of `stdio_init_all()` breaks something and no more output.

[image: Output from minicom]

Comment: If you remove the call to `multicore_fifo_pop_blocking()` (or place a `printf()` statement before it), do you see any output? That would help differentiate between "`core1_main` is not running at all" vs "`core1_main` is blocking and the fifo is working as you expect".

Comment: [pico_multicore - C-API](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/high_level.html#pico_multicore) provides both examples and reference.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot reproduce this problem. I started with a slightly modified version of your code (I wanted a loop in `core1_main` so that I didn't miss output before connecting to the serial port):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/multicore.h"

void core1_main()
{
    while (1) {
        printf("hello world from second core\n");
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}

int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();

    multicore_launch_core1(core1_main);
    printf("hello wow\n");

    uint32_t i = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("hello nice %u\n", i++);
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`, following the pico sdk documentation:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# initialize the SDK based on PICO_SDK_PATH
# note: this must happen before project()
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(my_project)

# initialize the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

add_executable(multicore_test
    multicore_test.c
)

target_link_libraries(multicore_test pico_stdlib pico_multicore)

pico_enable_stdio_usb(multicore_test 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(multicore_test 0)


pico_add_extra_outputs(multicore_test)
```

If I build the code:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

And then install the resulting `multicore_test.uf2` onto the Pico, when I connect to the serial port (`/dev/ttyACM0` on my system), I see:

```
hello world from second core
hello nice 3
hello world from second core
hello nice 4
hello world from second core
hello nice 5
hello world from second core
hello nice 6
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to initialize the TinyUSB stack by calling `stdio_init_all();` on core 1.

Move `stdio_init_all();` to core 0.  That will fix the issue.

That is also why @larsks didn't see the issue.  He placed `stdio_init_all();` on core 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Spinning up core 1 and after a few seconds it just stopped. My code looked like this:

```cpp
void main2() {
    printf("Entered core1 (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());

    while(1) {        
        printf("ping (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());        
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();

    printf("Entered core0 (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());

    multicore_launch_core1(main2);    

    while(1) {
        printf("ping (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

And the output I got was:

```
Entered core0 (core=0)
ping (core=0)
Entered core1 (core=1)
ping (core=1)
ping (core=0)
ping (core=0)
ping (core=0)
ping (core=0)
ping (core=0)
ping (core=0)
...
```

Core 1 printed one, sometimes a couple of times and then stopped. The solution to the problem was to sleep after `stdio_init_all()`.

```cpp
void main2() {
    printf("Entered core1 (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());

    while(1) {        
        printf("ping (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());        
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();

    // There isn't a strict rule that you must always call sleep_ms()
    // after stdio_init_all(). However, in some cases, it can be a helpful
    // precautionary measure to ensure that the UART has properly 
    // initialized and is ready to transmit data without any issues.
    sleep_ms(2000);

    printf("Entered core0 (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());

    multicore_launch_core1(main2);    

    while(1) {
        printf("ping (core=%d)\n", get_core_num());
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

I tried multiple times with and without sleep(). Without it I always got the problem and with it the problem always went away.

I didn't figure this one out by myself but asked ChatGPT. It told me:

> There isn't a strict rule that you must always call sleep_ms() after stdio_init_all(). However, in some cases, it can be a helpful precautionary measure to ensure that the UART has properly initialized and is ready to transmit data without any issues.

But it refused to tell me where this was documented. I googled it, but didn't find any other information about it. I am sure it is out there, I didn't look that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely stdio is not safe for multithreading.

Adding stdio_flush(); at the end of core1_main() could help.

Waiting a while after stdio_init_all() is also advicable for example:
while (!stdio_usb_connected()) {sleep_ms(100);} // wait until usb serial client/host is connected

Comment: This is not why.  The issue is that you can't initialize `stdio_init_all();` on core 1.  Moving `stdio_init_all();` to core 0 will fix the issue.

Comment: You are right that stdio_usb_init(); does nothing when invoked from core1. But even if you initialize it from core 0 I still believe you get similar problems (not safe for multithreading). I believe the test from larsks is successful because he adds a sleep statement of 1s next to the print statements for both cores and thus are less likely to collide.

Comment: The Pico-SDK adds a mutex around the TinyUSB code (i.e. function calls) for thread safety. https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/blob/master/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c.  From the Pico C/C++ SDK: `the SDK version of printf is always safe to call from both cores. malloc, calloc and free are additionally wrapped
to make it thread safe when you include the pico_multicore as a convenience for C++ programming, where some
object allocations may not be obvious.`